# Add a placeholder to {{}} in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have this editable field. looks like this

```
<editable model="option.title">{{option.title}}</editable>
```

I have tried adding a placeholder to the `{{}}` tags. Because at the moment it just shows the icon for editing the text area.

```
<editable model="option.title">{{option.title | 'Placeholder here'}}</editable>
```

This isn't working so obviously its not right, Is there any method of adding a placeholder?

I had used `ng-init` but i could only use one, issue is i have multiple {{}} tags.

Heres the editable directive

```
App.directive('editable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {model: '='},
        replace: false,
        template:
'<span>'+
    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="model" style="width: 100%; font-size: 18px" ng-show="edit" ng-enter="edit=false"></input>'+
        '<span ng-show="!edit">{{model}} <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:20px;"></i></span>'+
'</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.edit = false;
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(scope.edit = true);
                element.find('input').focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: Use {{option.title || 'Placeholder here'}} instead of {{option.title | 'Placeholder here'}}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit2** The cleaner way to do it would be to modify your directive to :

```
app.directive('editable', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: { model: '=', 
                 placeholder: '@'},
        replace: false,
        template:
'<span>'+
    '<input type="text" class="form-control"  ng-model="model" style="width: 100%; font-size: 18px" ng-show="edit" ng-enter="edit=false"></input>'+
        '<span ng-show="!edit">{{model || placeholder}} <i class="fa fa-pencil" style="font-size:20px;"></i></span>'+
'</span>',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.edit = false;
            element.bind('click', function() {
                scope.$apply(scope.edit = true);
                element.find('input').focus();
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Then you can do :

```
<editable model="option.title" placeholder="This is my placeholder"></editable>
```

**Old**

You can use :

`{{option.title ? option.title : 'Placeholder'}}`

or `{{option.title || 'Placeholder'}}`

If you want to add more complex logic to it you can create a filter :

```
app.filter('placeholder', function() {
  return function(input) {
    return input ? input : 'Placeholder';
  };
});
```

You can then do :

```
{{option.title | placeholder}}
```

Comment: HI there, I've tried both of the top methods and neither worked. Just adding the app.filter in now

Comment: @Tester123 Sorry, I didn't look into your directive deeply, I'm preparing a new code snippet for you.

Comment: Thanks Was extremely confused as to why it wasn't working!

Comment: @Tester123 : Eddited my answer, please let me know if it works for you